# how to ssh into linux lab from Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh

Facing problem to `ssh` into Linux from mac.

```
ssh: connect to host 35.184.51.144 port 22: Operation timed out
```

[image: man]

Comment: You'd want to check if the machine is reachable, whether ssh daemon is running on port 22 on that machine. Check the client and server logs in verbose after that. Should give some clue.

Comment: Try to add a `-v` option to the command line for more log output.